# NoReverseMatch while regex tester passes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to visit the following url in a browser: `http://localhost:8000/hourregistration/reminder/2016WK24/`

and I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand why it's failing with:

```
NoReverseMatch at /hourregistration/reminder/2016WK24/

Reverse for 'mailreminder' with arguments '('24',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['hourregistration/reminder/(?P<yearwknr>[0-9]{4}WK[0-9]{2})/$']

Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PP\PP\hourregistration\templates\hourregistration\slacker-table-and-form.html, error at line 99
```

My `urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'hourregistration'
...
url(r'^reminder/(?P<yearwknr>[0-9]{4}WK[0-9]{2})/$', views.mailreminder, name='mailreminder'),
```

For what it's worth `views.py`:

```
def mailreminder(request, yearwknr):
    year = yearwknr[:4]
    wknr = yearwknr[6:]
    if request.method == "GET":
        slackers = db.getSlackers(year, wknr)
        context = {'slackers':slackers, 
                   'yearwknr': wknr}
        return render(request, 'hourregistration/slacker-table-and-form.html', context)
    [omitted the POST path as it's not relevant]
```

Part of the template it fails on `slacker-table-and-form.html`. Which is all inside a `$(document).ready()`

```
    $('input#submit-form').click(function () {
        if ($('input#receiverList').val().length == 0) {
            $('#mail-warning').text('No recipients!');
        } else {

            $.ajax({
line 99 -->     url: "{% url 'hourregistration:mailreminder' yearwknr %}",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "html",
                data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken, 'to': $('input#receiverList').val(), 'subject': $('input#subject').val(), 'body': $('form-body').val()},
                success: function (data) {
                            $('#mail-warning').text('success!');
                        },
            });
        }
    });
```

`reverse()` works from a Django console:

```
reverse('hourregistration:mailreminder',kwargs={'yearwknr':'2016WK24'})
'/hourregistration/reminder/2016WK24/'
```

Using http://pythex.org/ my regex also seems to validate as expected. Yet, somehow Django only seems to capture the last bit of the regex. As a simple test I replaced the url with:

```
url(r'^reminder/(?P<yearwknr>.+)/$', views.mailreminder, name='mailreminder'),
```

and then it works. So I'm at least sure I'm fighting with the right `url()` (there's only 1 additional in the urls.py anyway, which is without an argument).

Why does my regex not match from a browser while it does from the Django console or external regex tester?

Comment: `with arguments '('24',)'`? That's interesting. Are you sure you are using the right string?

Comment: Pretty sure see http://i.imgur.com/LriODYy.png I already tried another browser for the sake of it.

Comment: Please copy and paste the entire message, and include it in your question. The image you linked to doesn't show where the error is occurring. It might also help to show the complete `mailreminder` view and template.

Comment: Had some unexpected absence, but I've now updated my original post with the View, Template and extra lines of the error message as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I was passing `wknr` in my Context (in the view) instead of 'yearwknr'

```
    context = {'slackers':slackers, 
               'yearwknr': wknr}
```

now

```
    context = {'slackers':slackers, 
               'yearwknr': yearwknr}
```

Now it's also clear why I was only getting the wknr part of the keyword argument.